# Does anyone know what these symbols mean? Cantonese? They appear in a tray marked "Hong Kong"

Tags: translation

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what these symbols mean? Cantonese? They appear in a tray marked "Hong Kong"

Comment: “至正之寶”, in seal script 

Answer (score 1):

- Hong Kong as the name for the islands started around 1810 during the Qing dynasty (嘉庆十五年) This is to point out these marking are misleading.
- like 水巷孑蠻 pointed it out, its "至正之寶" in the typeface of 小篆
  [image]

- the above image is coming from typeface converter - http://www.diyiziti.com/zhuanshu